# Switch case in php form not updating upon submit

Tags: php

Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758853/php-making-a-switch-statement-using-id-from-form-input).  I setup a form element case switch for another form element based on the input of text field CallType like this:

```
 <select id="CallType" name="CallType">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
```

I then setup my case switch like this but upon form post the value is not inserted into my database.  I can test this by using a static CallDesc text field and the form inserts fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Sample Switch:

```
  <?php 
    switch($_POST['CallType']) {

        case '1':
        echo '<input id="CallDesc" name="CallDesc" type="text" value="Air-conditioner / Heat Pumps" class="formTextfield_Medium" tabindex="3">';
        break;
        case '2':
        echo '<input id="CallDesc" name="CallDesc" type="text" value="Refrigerator / Ice (Makers/Machines) / Wine Cooler" class="formTextfield_Medium" tabindex="3">';
        break;
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: You have a missing " in the echo of case 1, on the name

Comment: What do you mean?  Can you provide a sample?

Comment: you have; name=CallDesc" it should be name="CallDesc" probably not the problem in this case but it is one thing that would pull up an error

Comment: sorry, typo when inputting the question...fixed now.

Comment: why would it display? you've got the type set to hidden... it should be type="text"

Comment: Its not a question of display...its a question of inserting the proper value into the text field (hidden or not).

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit better? from what you've said all I can tell is that you want the value of the <select> field to be inserted into the value of the input box...

Comment: In select CallType if user selects a value of 1, I want the form element CallDesc to be Air-conditioner / Heat Pumps

Comment: That's what I asked before, how did you know it wasn't if you couldn't see it? unless there's more code you haven't provided

Comment: i had it as "text" as well as "hidden" is what I mean.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did not include POST form element.  I opted to do this in Javascript and it was much more easier.  [Solution found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457175/how-do-you-use-javascript-to-populate-a-text-field-with-data-based-on-a-select-b).

Answer (score 0):

Your select's name is CallType, not SPG_CallType.

Furthermore, it might be easier for you to use an associative array or even better a database to manage this, rather than a switch statement.

Comment: Typo when setting up the question, its fixed.  Why would I use a database to query static fields that will not change?  Isn't that a waste of DB resources?

Comment: How should I know from the little code you provided that they would never change? You might add more. Who knows? I said an associative array was an option as well.

If you're not posting your actual code, we can't really help. You may have a typo in your actual code. Try a print_r on $_POST.

Comment: This is the code, this is all that's there.  A switch case is the best way to do this according to the referenced answer I was using.

Comment: Well, what was the result of the print_r?

Answer (score 0):

You needed to put it in a POST form in order for it to work:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
 <select id="CallType" name="CallType">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

Then the PHP worked as you posted it:

```
<?php 
switch($_POST['CallType']) {

    case '1':
    echo '<input id="CallDesc" name="CallDesc" type="text" value="Air-conditioner / Heat Pumps" class="formTextfield_Medium" tabindex="3">';
    break;
    case '2':
    echo '<input id="CallDesc" name="CallDesc" type="text" value="Refrigerator / Ice (Makers/Machines) / Wine Cooler" class="formTextfield_Medium" tabindex="3">';
    break;
}
?>
```

Since in the form I put action="" the PHP would obviously have to be on the same page. I should note that I'd normally use Javascript, or AJAX if it needs to be dynamic, in this case; simply because I find page loads while filling in a form annoying.